# How to TEST button initiated page redirect

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

I'm new to Salesforce and I'm trying to write some tests for our code. There is a button redirect initiated from the Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Happening__c" extensions="HappeningNewActionEvent" standardStyleSheets="false" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" action="{!init}">
```

Here is the apex code:

```
public with sharing class HappeningNewActionEvent {


private ApexPages.StandardController stdController;
public HappeningNewAction(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    this.stdController = stdController;
}

public PageReference init() {       
    company__Happening_New_Happeninig_Event__c happening = new company__Happening_New_Happeninig_Event__c(
        company__happening__c = stdController.getRecord().Id
    );  

    PageReference page = new ApexPages.StandardController(happening).view();
    page.setRedirect(true);
    return page;        
}
   }
```

To my understanding the controller redirects the page to the happening ID. I'm however having a hard time being able to replicate the ID on my test class:

```
@isTest
    private with sharing class HappeningNewActionEventUnitTest {

    static testMethod void TestRedirect(){
    PageReference pf  = Page.HappeningnNewActionEvent;
    Test.setCurrentPage(pf);

    company__Happening_Eveny__c newHE = new company__Happening_Event__c();

    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(newHE);
    HappeningNewActionEvent controller = new HappeningNewActionEvent(sc);
    String nextPage = controller.init().getUrl();

    //Verify that page fails without parameters
    System.assertNotEquals('/apex/failure=error=noParam', nextPage);


    //Verify that  page displays.
    System.assertEquals('/apex/happeningnewactionevent', nextPage);

}
 }
```

I'm having a bit hard time with the test. the controller.init().getURL() returns a null so I obviously cant get the ID forward, but as I'm a bit new with salesforce I cant find how to test for this.

Thanks.